# How to clean or discard a draft in Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

In documentation I have made change to title of topic that I don't think is relevant enough and I already have 10 change approvals queued.

I would like to discard it, but there is no way to do it when I go to `edit and retract`

[image]

Same goes where I added Summary section cannot cancel it even after deleting all text from summary section.

I have tried

```
jQuery.post('/post/discard-draft', {
    fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey,
    postType: 'ask',
});
```

but it didn't help.

**How can I discard my draft?**

Comment: should see "My drafts" on dashboard of the tag. Click gear icon

Comment: That is not obvious thing to do. This should be improved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from comment:

> See "My drafts" on dashboard of the tag. -> Click gear icon

[image]